# Cannot get Redis Cluster to run on Docker Compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, redis, redis-cluster

I'm trying to figure out how to run Redis cluster using Docker Compose.

However, I'm getting the following error:

> Error response from daemon: Ports are not available: exposing port TCP 0.0.0.0:6380 -> 0.0.0.0:0: listen tcp 0.0.0.0:6380: bind: Only one usage of each socket address (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted.

```yaml
version: '3.9'

services:
  dynamodb-local:
    container_name: dynamodb-local
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:latest
    command: -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -sharedDb -dbPath ./data
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./docker/dynamodb:/home/dynamodblocal/data
    working_dir: /home/dynamodblocal
    networks:
      - webnet

  redis-master: # Setting up master node
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6379:6379
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=master
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=my_master_password
    volumes:
      - ./docker/redis:/bitnami/redis/data # Redis master data volume
      - ./docker/redis/conf/redis.conf:/opt/bitnami/redis/conf/redis.conf # Redis master configuration volume
    networks:
      - webnet

  redis-replica:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    ports:
      - 6380-6382:6379
    depends_on:
      - redis-master
    environment:
      - REDIS_REPLICATION_MODE=slave
      - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=redis-master
      - REDIS_MASTER_PORT_NUMBER=6379
      - REDIS_MASTER_PASSWORD=my_master_password
      - REDIS_PASSWORD=my_replica_password
    deploy:
      replicas: 3
    networks:
      - webnet

networks:
  webnet:
    driver: bridge
```

Comment: The redis replica number 2 is starting on the same port as replica 1 - can you try separating them out into three different declarations with dedicated ports i.e not 6380-6382 but specific dedicated ports

Comment: @AsadAwadia removing the ports section worked.